# var is not detecting result of method with dynamic input

Tags: c#, dynamic, var

I have the following problem

```
private int GetInt(dynamic a)
{
    return 1;
}

private void UsingVar()
{
    dynamic a = 5;
    var x = GetInt(a);
}
```

But x is still dynamic.
I don't understand why.

[image: Wrong type]

Comment: Works for me https://dotnetfiddle.net/BTfGp3

Comment: @MichaelRandall So it means, the `.GetType ()` gets resolved at run-time.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since your argument `a` in the `GetInt` method call have the type dynamic, so the overload resolution occurs at **run time** instead of at **compile time**.

Based on [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/types/using-type-dynamic):

> Overload resolution occurs at run time instead of at compile time if one or more of the arguments in a method call have the type dynamic, or if the receiver of the method call is of type dynamic.

Actually by using the `dynamic` you are using the [late binding](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/200115/what-is-early-and-late-binding/200123#200123) (defers to later), and it means, the compiler can't verify it because it won't use any static type analysis anymore.

The solution would be using a cast like this:

```
var x = (int)GetInt(a);
```

The following is how the compiler is treating your code:

```
private void UsingVar()
{
    object arg = 5;
    if (<>o__2.<>p__0 == null)
    {
        Type typeFromHandle = typeof(C);
        CSharpArgumentInfo[] array = new CSharpArgumentInfo[2];
        array[0] = CSharpArgumentInfo.Create(CSharpArgumentInfoFlags.UseCompileTimeType, null);
        array[1] = CSharpArgumentInfo.Create(CSharpArgumentInfoFlags.None, null);
        <>o__2.<>p__0 = CallSite<Func<CallSite, C, object, object>>
           .Create(Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.Binder
           .InvokeMember(CSharpBinderFlags.InvokeSimpleName, "GetInt", null, typeFromHandle, array));
    }
    object obj = <>o__2.<>p__0.Target(<>o__2.<>p__0, this, arg);
}
```